# Get Frame Of line of Text of UILabel when Text Alignment in Center

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-text, textkit

My label size is `W= 190 H =322` and the text in label is in center alignment like[image]

I want an orange box character of line of text frame from UILabel

Comment: I want a ferrari, my own mansion and enough money to do anything I want. I won't get any of this unless i put some effort in though, i suggest you do the same with your problem. Instead of saying what you want, attempt the problem and, if still having problems, come back and display what you tried. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help guide you

Answer (score 0):

The frame of your UILabel should be the same size as I'ts content. Wrapped.
This is how you do it:

Without auto layout:

You should call sizeToFit on UILabel to shrink it to the text size, and then check I'ts frame.

```
textLabel.text = "@yourText";
textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
[textLabel sizeToFit];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(textLabel.frame.size.width, textLabel.frame.size.height);
```

With autolayout:

Just set "numberOfLines" to 0, and don't give the label a width constraint, and the label size will fit automatically.

## EDIT

Core text:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
label.text = @"Your text";
float yourFontSize = 20;
while ([label.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:yourFontSize]}].width > modifierFrame.size.width)
{
     yourFontSize--;
}
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:yourFontSize];
```

Comment: How it is possible using CoreText Framework or Textkit @PiratM